# naming convention for a function with multiple parameters

Tags: naming-conventions

what's the naming convention for a function that searches an entity by 4 parameters?

for instance ***GetCarByColourBrandStyleAndType*** sounds way too long although is descriptive enought IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use *SearchForCar* for instance?

The paramaters (I expect are type, brand, color...) should give clarification? You can always make one or more parameters optional when you have for example another function saying GetCarByBrandColor()